# ERROR The action 'NAVIGATE' with payload {"name":"InvoicesScreen","params":{"item":"Invoices"}} was not handled by any navigator

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

Hello everything is fine? I am developing a commercial application. And I'm facing an issue related to Stack and Drawer navigation when accessed/clicked for the first time.

This app that logs in (**ScreenLogin**) consuming an API, uses only the CPF (personal password) to authenticate. Once authentication is successful, it is directed to Home (**ScreenHome**), where the error will occur.

When this login is done for the first time, this error occurs, that is, when the login is done for the first time, the app crashes. Remembering, opening the application for the second time onwards does not give an error, and it works perfectly normal.

### The error:

*When I click **onPress={this.props.navigation.navigate("InvoicesScreen")}***

> ERROR  The action 'NAVIGATE' with payload {"name":"InvoicesScreen","params":{"item":"Invoices"}} was not handled by any navigator.
> Do you have a screen named 'InvoicesScreen'?
> If you're trying to navigate to a screen in a nested navigator, see https://reactnavigation.org/docs/nesting-navigators#navigating-to-a-screen-in-a-nested-navigator.
> This is a development-only warning and won't be shown in production.

When I click ***onPress={() => this.props.navigation.openDrawer()}***

> ERROR  TypeError: undefined is not a function, js engine: hermes

### Below my code:

#### **App.js**

```
if (appLoaded && fontsReady && imagesReady) {
    return (
        <NativeBaseProvider>
            <RootSiblingParent>
                <StatusBar backgroundColor={Colors.PRIMARY} barStyle='light-content'/>
                <NavigationContainer>
                    {isLogged ? <Logged/> : <Guest/>}
                </NavigationContainer>  
            </RootSiblingParent>
        </NativeBaseProvider>
    );
}
```

#### **Login.js**

```
_getData = async () => {   

        this.setState({ buttonVisible: false });
        const { senha }  = this.state;

        if (senha.length <= 0) {
            Toast.show('O campo CPF/CNPJ não pode ser vazio', Toast.LONG, { backgroundColor: 'blue', fontSize: 28, fontFamily: 'Montserrat-Regular' });
            this.setState({ buttonVisible: true });
            return;
        }

        return await fetch(Configs.URL+`json/data_contratos.php?cpf=${senha}&senha=${senha}&ip=${Configs.IP}`)
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((responseJson) => {
            this.setState({
                dataContrato: responseJson.contratos,
                contrato: responseJson.contratos[0].contrato,
                keystatus: responseJson.contratos[0].status.trim(),
                contContrato: responseJson.contratos.length
            }); 
            const { contContrato, contrato, keystatus } = this.state;
            if (contContrato > 1) {
                this._openModalContratos();
                this.setState({ buttonVisible: true });
                return null;
            } else {
                AsyncStorage.setItem('keycontrato'+Configs.SLUG, contrato.toString());
                AsyncStorage.setItem('keycpfcnpj'+Configs.SLUG, senha);
                AsyncStorage.setItem('keysenha'+Configs.SLUG, senha);
                AsyncStorage.setItem('keystatus'+Configs.SLUG, keystatus);
                this._goHome();
            }
        }).catch((e)=> {
            Toast.show('O CPF/CNPJ não foi localizado.', Toast.LONG, { backgroundColor: 'blue', fontSize: 28, fontFamily: 'Montserrat-Regular' });
            this.setState({ buttonVisible: true });
        });
        
    }
```

```
_goHome = () => {
        const resetAction = CommonActions.reset({
            index: 0,
            routes: [
                { name: 'HomeScreen' }
            ],
        });
        this.props.navigation.dispatch(resetAction);
    };
```

### Navigation:

#### Guest.js

```
import { Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import React from 'react';
import HelpsScreen from '../screens/Helps';
import HomeScreen from '../screens/Home';
import LoginScreen from '../screens/Login';
import Colors from '../utils/Colors';

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

export default function StackNavigation(props){

    const buttonLeft = () => {
        return (
            <Ionicons name={'md-arrow-back'} onPress={ () => { navigation.goBack() }} style={styles.arrowbackicon}/>
        )
    };
    
    const navigatorOptions = {
        headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: Colors.PRIMARY,
            shadowColor: 'transparent',
            elevation: 0,
            shadowOpacity: 0,
        },
        headerTitleStyle: {
            fontSize: 18,
            color: Colors.BLACK
        },
        headerTitleAlign: 'center',
        headerBackTitleVisible:false,
        headerTintColor: Colors.BLACK
    }

    return (
        <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={navigatorOptions}>
            <Stack.Screen name="LoginScreen" component={LoginScreen} options={{ headerShown: false }}/>
            <Stack.Screen name="HelpsScreen" component={HelpsScreen} options={{ headerShown: false }}/>
            <Stack.Screen name="HomeScreen" component={HomeScreen} options={{ headerShown: false }}/>
        </Stack.Navigator>
    )
    
}
```

#### Logged.js

```
import { Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import DetectorScreen from '../screens/Detector';
import HomeScreen from '../screens/Home';
import InternetScreen from '../screens/Internet';
import InvoicesScreen from '../screens/Invoices';
import LoginScreen from '../screens/Login';
import ReactivateScreen from '../screens/Reactivate';
import SpeedScreen from '../screens/Speed';
import SupportScreen from '../screens/Support';
import SupportSendScreen from '../screens/SupportSend';

import Colors from '../utils/Colors';

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

export default function Logged(props){

    const {navigation} = props;
    
    const navigationOptions = {
        headerStyle: styles.headerStyle,
        headerBackTitle: null,
        headerTintColor: Colors.PRIMARY,
        headerTitleAlign: 'center',
        headerTitleStyle: {
            textAlign: 'center',
            alignSelf: 'center',
            justifyContent: 'space-between',
            fontSize: 16,
            color: Colors.PRIMARY,
            fontWeight: 'bold'
        },
        headerBackTitleVisible:false,
    }

    const buttonLeft = () => {
        return (
            <Ionicons name={'md-arrow-back'} onPress={ () => { navigation.goBack() }} style={styles.arrowbackicon}/>
        )
    };

    return (
        <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={navigationOptions}>
            <Stack.Screen name="HomeScreen" component={HomeScreen} options={{ headerShown: false }}/>
            <Stack.Screen name="InvoicesScreen" component={InvoicesScreen} options={{ headerShown: false }}/>
            <Stack.Screen name="ReactivateScreen" component={ReactivateScreen} options={{ headerShown: false }}/>
            <Stack.Screen name="SupportScreen" component={SupportScreen} options={{ headerShown: false }}/>
            <Stack.Screen name="SupportSendScreen" component={SupportSendScreen} options={{ headerShown: false }}/>
            <Stack.Screen name="SpeedScreen" component={SpeedScreen} options={{ headerShown: false }}/>
            <Stack.Screen name="InternetScreen" component={InternetScreen} options={{ headerShown: false }}/>
            <Stack.Screen name="DetectorScreen" component={DetectorScreen} options={{ headerShown: false }}/>
            <Stack.Screen name="LoginScreen" component={LoginScreen} options={{ headerShown: false }}/>
        </Stack.Navigator>
    )
    
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    headerStyle:{
        backgroundColor: Colors.PRIMARY,
        shadowOpacity: 0,
        borderBottomWidth: 0,
        elevation: 0,
    },
})
```

#### Navigation.js

```
import { createDrawerNavigator } from "@react-navigation/drawer";
import React from "react";
import Logged from './Logged';
import SideMenu from './SideMenu';

const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

const Navigation = () => {
  return (
    <Drawer.Navigator initialRouteName="app" drawerContent={(props) => <SideMenu {...props} />}>
      <Drawer.Screen name="main" component={Logged} options={{ headerShown: false }}/>
    </Drawer.Navigator>
  );
};

export default Navigation;
```

Help me, I'm a beginner!
Since Thanks!
Eddie

### **SOLUTION!**

I created a splash to be shown to the user after login, and now it works correctly!

Comment: Looks like it’s the same issue than here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75783899/11692562

Comment: It's not my case. Thanks!

Comment: **SOLUTION!**

I created a splash to be shown to the user after login, and now it works correctly!